# OrientDB deep traversal until specific class

Tags: graph, pattern-matching, orientdb

So I have simple graph. The most left nodes are 'Team' class. The second most right (gray one) is 'Sport' class node.

[image: SimpleGraph]

I need to find all Teams which relates to specific Sport

When I have only one Team node this query works:

```
MATCH {class:Team, as: team} --> {class: Sport, maxDepth: 10}
RETURN team.Abbreviation
```

After I've added second node of 'Team' class I've started to get this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Invalid pattern to match!
```

If I remove 'maxDepth' it works but returns nothing

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely a bug, I'm checking it.
As a quick work-around you can add a condition to the first element in the pattern, so that you force the executor to start from there:

```
 MATCH {class:Team, as: team, where:(true)} --> {class: Sport, maxDepth: 10}
 RETURN team.Abbreviation
```

Even better, remove the "class" from the right hand:

```
 MATCH {class:Team, as: team} --> {where: (@class = 'Sport'), maxDepth: 10}
 RETURN team.Abbreviation
```

The problem here is that the pattern is being evaluated in the wrong direction (from right to left), with the above work-around you are forcing OrientDB to evaluate it from left to right

Comment: Good news, I just pushed a fix on 2.2.x branch, now the original query works fine. The fix will be released with 2.2.30